# SQL Server - insufficient memory (mscorlib) / 'the operation could not be completed'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been working on building a new database. I began by building the structure within the database it is replacing and populating this as I created each set of tables. Once I had made additions I would drop what had been created and execute the code to build the structure again and a separate file to insert the data. I repeated this until the structure and content was complete to ensure each stage was as I intended.

The insert file is approximately 30mb with 500,000 lines of code (I appreciate this is not the best way to do this but for various reasons I cannot use alternative options). The final insert completed and took approximately 30 minutes.

A new database was created for me, the structure executed successfully but the data would not insert. I received the first error message shown below. I have looked into this and it appears I need to use the sqlcmd utility to get around this, although I find it odd as it worked in the other database which is on the same sever and has the same autogrow settings.

However, when I attempted to save the file after this error I received the second error message seen below. When I selected OK it took me to my file directory as it would if I selected Save As, I tried saving in a variety of places but received the same error.

I attempted to copy the code into notepad to save my changes but the code would not copy to the clipboard. I accepted I would lose my changes and rebooted my system. If I reopen this file and attempt to save it I receive the second error message again.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if you try one of this... check log file size, maybe you must increase the file just for the insert operation or check if you inserting with no log option (BULK INSERT)

Comment: @Beto I originally tried to bulk insert but the data would not upload from its current location and I understand it needed to be moved to the server, this may have been a privileges issue but I cannot recall.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. This looks more like an issue with SSMS and not the SQL Server DB/engine.
If you've been doing few times, possibly Management Studio ran out of RAM?
Have you tried breaking INSERT into batches/smaller files?